# how to achieve this in xml schema?

Tags: xsd

How to achieve the below using schema. The internal structure of **b** element is changing based upon the context (**c** element remains constant but the 2nd element keeps changing). I could have used **choice** if there are only few potential combinations but I have plenty.

**sample 1**

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c></c>
      <d></d>
   <b>
</a>
```

**sample 2**

```
<a>
   <b>
      <c></c>
      <e></e>
   <b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to use xsd:any or xsd:anyType. I can't quite tell based on your example which is correct.

Comment: thx but i doesn't want to do that. I am checking if there is an alternate option...may be a clever use of substitutionGroup

Comment: I think with substituonGroup you have to specify the possible substitutions. If you are able to do that, then you should be able to use substitution group.